# if else in r using %in%

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

Let us assume that my first dataset is iris

```
 data(iris)
 head(iris)

   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
   5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
   4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
   4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
   4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
   5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
   5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

My second dataset contains a column type as shown below

```
   type
   setosa
   veranica
   Big Rosa
   virginica
```

I am trying to generate a sixth column in iris dataset with values Yes and No, Yes if values in iris$Species == 2ndDataset$type else no.

I am interested in doing this using %in% option. I tried but failed, this is what I did so far

```
  iris[(as.character(iris$Species ) %in% as.character(2ndDataset$type)) ,  Result = 1, Result = 0]
```

Need help.

Comment: I don't see any if statement. doesn't `as.character(iris$Species) %in% as.character(2ndDataset$type) + 0L`  work?

Comment: @rawr, no ..getting an error  `unused argument (Result = 1, Result = 0) ` i am trying to avoid if else and use %in%

Comment: If your second data frame is called `mydf`, this line works for me. `mutate(iris, check = as.character(Species) %in% as.character(mydf$type) + 0L)`

Comment: but I didnt use that argument, so that's why I dont get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check equality in an *ordered* manner (i.e., if element i of vector type is the same of element i in vector species) you cannot use %in%, because it checks if element i of vector type is contained wherever in vector species.

I can think of two ways of doing what you are looking for:

```
# Generates dummy data
data(iris)
iris2 = iris
iris = cbind(iris, Values = NA)
# Creates a difference between iris2$Species (type) and iris$Species
iris2$Species[1] = "virginica"
```

First way (without ifelse):

```
iris$Values = as.character(iris$Species) == as.character(iris2$Species)
iris$Values[iris$Values == TRUE] = "Yes"
iris$Values[iris$Values == FALSE] = "No"
```

Second way (quicker):

```
iris$Values = ifelse(as.character(iris$Species) == as.character(iris2$Species), "Yes", "No")
```